# Как вычислить среднее арифметическое элементов, расположенных между минимальным и максимальным?

Tags: c, оптимизация

Получилось слишком громоздко, можно ли сделать короче это задание?

> В одномерном массиве А(10) вычислить среднее арифметическое элементов, расположенных между минимальным и максимальным.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int mas[10], result = 0, max, min, i, max_in=0, min_in=0, am, count = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            printf("Введите элемент mas[%d] = ",i);
            scanf("%d", &mas[i]);
        }
        max=mas[0];
        min = mas[0];
        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            if(mas[i]>max){
                max=mas[i];
                max_in = i;
            }else if(mas[i]<min){
                min=mas[i];
                min_in = i;
            }
        }
        if(max_in<min_in){
                count = (min_in - max_in) - 1;
                if(count == 0){
                      printf("Кол-во = 0");  
                }else{
                for(i = max_in + 1; i<min_in; i++){
                        result += mas[i];
                }}   
        }else if(max_in>min_in){
                count = (max_in - min_in) - 1;
                if(count == 0){
                      printf("Кол-во = 0");  
                }else{
                for(i = min_in + 1; i<max_in; i++){
                        result += mas[i];
                }}
        }
        am = result/count;
        printf("Результат  =  %d \n", am);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: а что высчитывать, если максимальных/минимальных  значений несколько? А если все элементы одинаковы?

Comment: И "между" - включительно или исключительно?

Comment: не знаю), есть такое задание, больше ничего не дано. Надеюсь на благосклонность заказчика(препода)... Неоднозначное тз

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, если действовать исключительно (не включая минимум и максимум) и рассматривая первые же минимум и максимум среди равных, то, например, так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int m, max, min, imax = 0, imin = 0, d[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("Введите элемент mas[%d] = ",i);
        scanf("%d", &m);
        if (i == 0)
            max = min = d[0] = m;
        else
        {
            d[i] = d[i-1] + m;
            if (m > max) max = m, imax = i;
            else if (m < min) min = m, imin = i;
        }
    }
    if (imax < imin) { m = imin; imin = imax; imax = m; }
    if (imax - 1 <= imin) printf("no elements\n");
    else printf("%lf\n",((double)(d[imax-1] - d[imin]))/(imax-imin-1));

}
```

Надеюсь, числа не такие, чтоб вызвать переполнение при суммировании :)

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, что по мнению преподавателя является "громоздким", поэтому постарался использовать парадигму функционального программирования для облегчения читаемости кода. Ну и в некоторых моментах специально ужал количество строк, вдруг имелся ввиду объём.

Мой вариант

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <limits.h>

int getMaxOrMin(int* arr, bool isMax) {
    int maxOrMin = isMax ? INT_MIN : INT_MAX;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > maxOrMin && isMax)
            maxOrMin = arr[i];
        else if (arr[i] < maxOrMin && !isMax)
            maxOrMin = arr[i];
    }
    return maxOrMin;
}
int getIndex(int* arr, int num) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == num)
            return i;
    }
}
double getAvg(int* arr, int max_i, int min_i) {
    int begin = max_i < min_i ? max_i : min_i, end = max_i > min_i ? max_i : min_i, 
    count = 0, sum = 0;
    for (int i = begin + 1; i < end; i++, count++)
        sum += arr[i];
    return sum / count;
}
int main() {
    int arr[10], max, min, max_i, min_i;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("Введите элемент arr[%d] = ", i);
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    max = getMaxOrMin(arr, true);
    min = getMaxOrMin(arr, false);
    printf("Среднее арифметическое = %lf", getAvg(arr, getIndex(arr, max), getIndex(arr, min)));
    return 0;
}
```